# Angular Router Ordering?

Tags: angular, router

Please to explain what the difference between 2 code snippet below:

1. `const routes: Routes = [
   {
   path: '',
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
   component: MainComponent,
   children: [
     {
       path: '',
       component: DashboardComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/add',
       component: AddItemComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:type/sandbox',
       component: SandboxComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:id',
       component: EditWrapperComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:account/:id',
       component: EditWrapperComponent
     }
   ]
   }
   ];`
2. const routes: Routes = [
   {
   path: '',
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
   component: MainComponent,
   children: [
     {
       path: '',
       component: DashboardComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/add',
       component: AddItemComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:id',
       component: EditWrapperComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:account/:id',
       component: EditWrapperComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'items/:type/sandbox',
       component: SandboxComponent
     }
   ]
   }
   ];

The code snippet 1 works as well when I call `localhost:4200/items/app/sandbox` (app is type)
but code snippet 2 doesn't work.

I don't know why so please help explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code snippet 2, `/items/app/sandbox` is routed to `'items/:account/:id` because of ordering.